# Creating SQL value with both number and escaped characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm looking to create a SQL query with both a field and some escape characters to make it easier for a client to upload the data to their system.
Here's what I've created:

```
Select
    [Int Field],
    Str("'" + [Int field] + "',") as client field,
etc.
```

The field runs fine, but refuses to show the special characters, and just shows the field (albeit centered on the space designated for it) with no numbers. When I use the '', it doesn't force them to appear, yet when I separate the field it shows.

I need it to show like

```
'123123',
'123124',
'123125',

etc.
```

Is there any way to create a SQL query that will output something like this?

Comment: show your code?

Comment: @SqlZim I did? It's literally a Select statement on that field, but I'll add that to clarify.

Comment: Which version of SQL server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str()` has an optional `length` parameter, default is 10, and an optional `decimal` parameter, default is 0. You can use the `len()` of the `[int field]` or you can just use `convert(varchar(10),[Int field])` to convert it to a string.

Also, you can't add strings to the `[int field]` before converting it.

Try this:

```
select
    [Int Field]
  , '''' + convert(varchar(10),[Int field])  + ''',' as clientfield
  , '''' + Str([Int field],len([Int field])) + ''',' as clientfield2
...
```